# Como mostrar el log de una rama específica de Git sin mostrar la rama master

Tags: git

estoy intentado mostrar en la consola el log de una rama en concreto:

```
git log nombre_rama
```

El problema es que aparte de mostrar el log de la rama en cuestión, me saca el log también de la rama master.

Con esto, se puede evitar, pero yo creo que tiene que haber una forma de hacerlo sin negar la rama master con el símbolo ^:

```
git log nombre_rama ^master
```

Comment: Añado que me ocurre incluso estando activa en el prompt la rama de la que quiero mostrar el log.

Comment: en el entorno del desarro web hay que mostrar un directorio personal gitadd "tracked"eso te dara como resultado index.html o depende si el sistema operativo es linux o apple cambio los comandos body-color.red estilos.css despues preparacion y te vlleva a un git commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quizás tengas un error de concepto... Imagina el siguiente escenario.

- En un repositorio recién estrenado hago dos commits que llamaré A y B (rama master)
- Creo entonces una nueva rama llamada "nueva"
- En la rama nueva creo un par de commits más (llamados C y D)
- En la rama master por otro lado se sigue trabajando y se hacen otros dos commits (E y F)

La situación por tanto es la siguiente:

[image: grafo git]

Si haces un `git log nueva` ¿qué esperas que te salga?

Como se ve en la figura "nueva" no es más que una "etiqueta" que está señalando a un commit (al commit D en este caso). `git log` simplemente recorre todos los commits que va encontrando desde el commit señalado hacia abajo, siguiendo la línea de "padres", es decir, el padre del D es el C, el padre del C es el B y el padre del B es el A, por lo que al final sale esto:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph  nueva
* 57ab205 D
* e87810e C
* d4c209f B
* 4f0fef5 A
```

En realidad no te está mostrando commits de master (no aparecen F y E), pero es completamente normal que aparezcan los commits B y A, ya que aunque esos commits fueron hechos en la rama master, también forman parte de la rama nueva, al haberse bifurcado.

Dicho de otro modo **una rama no es una colección de commits**, sino simplemente un nombre (o un apuntador si prefieres) a un commit particular (con la característica de que el apuntador se actualiza cada vez que haces un commit nuevo teniendo esa rama activa). El log te muestra una secuencia de commits enlazados partiendo desde el señalado por el apuntador hacia atrás.

Dicho esto, veamos algunos comandos para mostrar diferentes "vistas" de esta historia.

#### Mostrar todas las ramas realmente

```
$  git log --oneline --graph --all
* ddfa687 F
* 97e4368 E
| * 57ab205 D
| * e87810e C
|/
* d4c209f B
* 4f0fef5 A
```

Aquí sale la historia completa, con sus bifurcaciones

### Mostrar solo una rama

Es decir, el último commit de esa rama y desde ese hacia atrás. Este es el comportamiento por defecto y por supuesto debe incluir los commits A y B como vimos

```
$ git log --oneline --graph nueva
* 57ab205 D
* e87810e C
* d4c209f B
* 4f0fef5 A
```

En caso de que quieras ver la rama master también te saldrán A y B:

```
git log --oneline --graph master
* ddfa687 F
* 97e4368 E
* d4c209f B
* 4f0fef5 A
```

### Mostrar los commits que hay en una rama pero no en la otra

Por ejemplo, los que hay en nueva pero no en master:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph master..nueva
* 57ab205 D
* e87810e C
```

O viceversa:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph nueva..master
* ddfa687 F
* 97e4368 E
```

### Casos más complicados

En caso de que tengas múltiples ramas entremezcladas puedes querer omitir los de una rama en particular (que también estén en la que queremos ver). Para eso sería la sintaxis de "negación", pero en este caso que tenemos solo dos ramas los resultados serían equivalentes a los antes vistos para la sintaxis `..`

```
$ git log --oneline --graph nueva ^master
* 57ab205 D
* e87810e C
```

```
git log --oneline --graph ^nueva master
* ddfa687 F
* 97e4368 E
```

Comment: Solo un pequeño comentario, aunque la explicación es muy buena. Técnicamente, las ramas en git no son más que **apuntadores a revisiones** (ni más allá ni más acá). Y precisamente porque son apuntadores es que uno los puede crear, borrar, mover, renombrar a conveniencia.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pues sí que tenía un concepto equivocado, es que estoy comenzando con Git. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @eftshift0 Gracias por el comentario. Eso mismo que dices es lo que creía haber dicho yo, pero releyendo me doy cuenta de que no fui muy claro y he editado la respuesta para mejorarla.